# Bootstrap Form to Database

Tags: php, html, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

I created a bootstrap form and want to include the data from the form into my database. My problem is that it is not working and I have no idea why. In my opinion everything is correct. I am looking for hours now but I can't find the issue.

You can find my form here: http://schulkantine.ccsolution.at/registration.php
Please do not look at the style, I have to customize it later.

Here is my register.php! Database connection is working.

```
<?php
// Create connection credentials
$db_host = 'localhost';
$db_name = 'DBNAME';
$db_user = 'DBUSER';
$db_pass = 'DBPASSWORD';

// Create mysqli object
$connect = new mysqli ($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);

// Error Handler
if ($connect->connect_error) {
    printf ("Connection failed: %s\n", $connect->connect_error);
    exit();
}   
?>

<?php
// Check if form is submitted
if (isset ($_POST['submit'])) {
    $anrede = mysqli_real_escape_string ($connect, $_POST['anrede']);
    $vorname = mysqli_real_escape_string ($connect, $_POST['vorname']);
    $nachname = mysqli_real_escape_string ($connect, $_POST['nachname']);
    $strasse = mysqli_real_escape_string ($connect, $_POST['strasse']);
    $plz = mysqli_real_escape_string ($connect, $_POST['plz']);
    $ort = mysqli_real_escape_string ($connect, $_POST['ort']);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string ($connect, $_POST['email']);
    $telefon = mysqli_real_escape_string ($connect, $_POST['telefon']);

    // Validate Input
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO user (anrede, firstname_parent, lastname_parent, street_parent, plz_parent, city_parent, email, phonenumber_parent)
VALUES ('$anrede', '$vorname', '$nachname', '$strasse', '$plz', '$ort', '$email', '$telefon')") or die(mysql_error()); 
    }
    ?>
```

Hope someone can help me and tell me what my error is!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing

```
INSERT INTO user (anrede, firstname_parent, lastname_parent, street_parent, plz_parent, city_parent, email, phonenumber_parent) VALUES ('$anrede', '$vorname', '$nachname', '$strasse', '$plz', '$ort', '$email', '$telefon')"
```

to

```
INSERT INTO `user` (`anrede`, `firstname_parent`, `lastname_parent`, `street_parent`, `plz_parent`, `city_parent`, `email`, `phonenumber_parent`) VALUES ('$anrede', '$vorname', '$nachname', '$strasse', '$plz', '$ort', '$email', '$telefon')"
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace this line in your registration.php file. You forget to add "name" attribute so your condition **if (isset ($_POST['submit']))** not work.

```
   <button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-custom pull-right">Send</button>
```